# Activity called via PendingIntent getting destroyed automatically

Tags: android, android-activity, android-pendingintent

I have an **Activity** with following special properties set in manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".LightUp"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:process=":listener"
        android:taskAffinity="" >
    </activity>
```

Inside this activity, I'm scheduling an **AlarmManager** to use this **PendingIntent** to call itself after sometime. **AlarmManager** is necessary because phone will go to sleep while this activity is on screen, and I don't want to hold a wakelock.

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 10,
                new Intent(this, LightUp.class)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

So when Alarm manager fires, I'm getting the new Intent in **onNewIntent()** function as usual. Which means intent is coming to same activity.
Problem is the activity gets destroyed after **onNewIntent**. Even if I have absolutely no code in **onNewIntent**, I can see from logs that **onDestroy** is getting called anyway.

So question is why  is Destroy being called? What can I do to keep the activity running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found the culprit. It's the **noHistory** property causing the problem.
Official documentation says

***android:noHistory*** :: Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen

Well, technically I didn't leave the screen while calling PendingIntent, weird that finish is being called. After removing **noHistory**, it's not destroying.

Comment: "when the user navigates away from it" --- I bet it means when onPause is called. So yeah, onPause is called automatically before onNewIntent, and that's the reason I guess

Answer (score 0):

try this

**Activity** in **Manifest**

```
<activity
  android:name=".LightUp"
  android:launchMode="singleTop"
</activity>
```

**Java Code**

```
Intent notificationintent = new Intent(context, LightUp.class);
notificationintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), notificationintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
  System.out.println("new intent received");
  // do what ever you want to do here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I already tried that. Not working. EDIT : Still not

Comment: Code is not relevant here.  Believe me I'm not calling finish() anywhere myself

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<activity
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
</activity>
```

By default, if you call an activity with an intent, a new instance of that activity will be created and displayed, even if another instance is already running. To avoid this the activity must be flagged that, it should not be instantiated multiple times. To achieve this you have to set the launchMode of the activity to `singleTask`.

Comment: I already stated in question that I'm getting onNewIntent correctly. So it is not a multiple instance problem

Comment: Yes, but as you have stated that `onDestroy()` is getting called, which means existing instance is getting destroyed and a new one is getting created therefore i have posted this answer.

Comment: If your problem is not solved, could you please try without setting the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` in the Intent as you have already set `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` in Manifest file

Comment: Tested a lot of variables. See my answer for what worked for me. Thanks anyway